# routing problem in laravel 8 by using href tag using blade?

Tags: laravel

my route:

```php
Route::get('categories','App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController@index');
```

Controller:

```php
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
        public function index($id){
           $articles=Article::where('Category','=',$id)->get();
           return view('categories',['articles'=>$articles]);
        }
}
```

View :

```html
<ul>
    @foreach ($categories as $item)
        <li>
            <a href={{ route('categories', ['id'=>$item->id]) }}>{!! $item->Name !!}</a>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

and this is error:

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
Route [categories] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\RTT\resources\views\partial\master.blade.php)
```

Comment: You need to define a name route. You just miss a `->name('categories')` here, as `Route::get('categories','App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController@index')->name('categories');` see the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#named-routes

Answer (score 0):

you should define the name that you use in your blade file and you should add id in your route like this:-

```
Route::get('categories/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController@index')->name('categories');
```

notic , laravel 8 add miner change in routes to be like this :-

```
Route::get(
    '/categories/{id}',
    [CategoryController::class, 'index']
)->name('categories');
```